# How to pass flags to mobile Chrome using Selenoid Docker images

Tags: android, google-chrome, docker, selenoid

I am trying to have Chrome launch without the "Welcome to Chrome" screen and can't seem to figure out the correct way to do so using Selenoid with the provided Android Docker images.

I used the automate_android.sh to create the container image and followed all the prompts, deviating from the default only when asked for version numbers and when it asked if I wanted to install Chrome.

Chrome will load but regardless of what I put in my test, I can't seem to get it to bypass the welcome screen.

Currently my config looks like this:

```
const merge = require('deepmerge');
const wdioConf = require('./wdio.conf.js');

exports.config = merge(wdioConf.config, {  
  capabilities: [
        {
            version: '8.1',
            browserName: 'android',
            chromedriverArgs: {
              args: [ '--disable-fre', '--no-default-browser-check', '--no-first-run' ],
            },
            "selenoid:options" : 
            {
              skin: "WVGA854",
              enableVNC: true,
              enableLog: true
            }
        }
    ]
}, {clone: false});
```

I have tried changing chromedriverArgs to "goog:chromeOptions" and chromeOptions.  Ive tried moving all three combinations inside the "selenoid:options" as well.

I suspect I am just doing something wrong but would appreciate any assist anyone can provide.

```
Versions
Selenoid: 1.9.1
Android: 8.1 and 8.0
WebdriverIO: 5.4.19
Docker: 18.09.2, build 6247962
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `chrome` as `browserName`. This is how Appium works.

Comment: When I make the recommended switch, it launches the chrome image and not the android image.